# python list of lists to dict when key appear many times

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I know to write something simple and slow with loop, but I need it to run super fast in big scale.

input:

```
lst = [[1, 1, 2], ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"]]
```

desired out put:

```
d = {1 : ["txt1", "txt2"], 2 : "txt3"]
```

There is something built-in at python which make `dict()` extend key instead replacing it?

```
dict(list(zip(lst[0], lst[1])))
```

Comment: there is no way to let this "run super fast in big scale." - you need to iterate all elements, you need to create inner lists, you need to either check/add or use something like defaultdict.

Comment: You *should* want `['txt3']`, not `'txt3'`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `dict.setdefault`:

```
out = {}
for k, v in zip(*lst):
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

Output:

```
{1: ['txt1', 'txt2'], 2: ['txt3']}
```

If you want the element itself for singleton lists, one way is adding a condition that checks for it while you build an output dictionary:

```
out = {}
for k,v in zip(*lst):
    if k in out: 
        if isinstance(out[k], list):
            out[k].append(v)
        else:
            out[k] = [out[k], v]
    else:
        out[k] = v
```

or if `lst[0]` is sorted (like it is in your sample), you could use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby
out = {}
pos = 0
for k, v in groupby(lst[0]):
    length = len([*v])
    if length > 1:
        out[k] = lst[1][pos:pos+length]
    else:
        out[k] = lst[1][pos]
    pos += length
```

Output:

```
{1: ['txt1', 'txt2'], 2: 'txt3'}
```

But as @timgeb notes, it's probably not something you want because afterwards, you'll have to check for data type each time you access this dictionary (if value is a list or not), which is an unnecessary problem that you could avoid by having all values as lists.

Comment: Note that OP does not want single element lists. Which is misguided, of course.

Comment: @timgeb Thanks for pointing it out; and I agree with your comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `defaultdict` to group the strings by their corresponding key, then make a second pass through the list to extract the strings from singleton lists. Regardless of what you do, you'll need to access every element in both lists at least once, so *some* iteration structure is necessary (and even if you don't explicitly use iteration, whatever you use will almost definitely use iteration under the hood):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [[1, 1, 2], ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"]]

result = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in zip(lst[0], lst[1]):
    result[key].append(value)

for key in result:
    if len(result[key]) == 1:
        result[key] = result[key][0]

print(dict(result)) # Prints {1: ['txt1', 'txt2'], 2: 'txt3'}
```

Comment: Note that OP does not want single element lists. Which is misguided, of course.

Comment: Edited, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with large datasets it may be useful to add a `pandas` solution.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> lst = [[1, 1, 2], ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3"]]
>>> s = pd.Series(lst[1], index=lst[0])
>>> s 
1    txt1
1    txt2
2    txt3
>>> s.groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_dict()
{1: ['txt1', 'txt2'], 2: ['txt3']}
```

Note that this also produces lists for single elements (e.g. `['txt3']`) which I highly recommend. Having both lists and strings as possible values *will* result in bugs because both of those types are iterable. You'd need to remember to check the type each time you process a dict-value.